# StackPanel Collapsed and Visible on Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, styles

I am trying to show one collapsed stackpanel on button click, but I'm having problems so I tried reverse my thoughts and I was able to collapse an visible stackpanel. But unfortunately I was unable to implement the behavior I want, show an collapsed stack panel on button click. To the code :D

**XAML**

```
<Button x:Name="sentButton" Content="Add Friend" Style="{DynamicResource FlatButtonStyle}" Margin="493,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="106"/>
    <StackPanel Style="{DynamicResource stackCollapsed}" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Label Content="Invite Friends" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,477,0" Height="32" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="26,0,0,0">
            <Label Content="Enter your friend's email" Width="222" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{DynamicResource MyTextBox}" x:Name="textBoxEmail" Width="298"/>
            <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Send" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Width="77" Style="{DynamicResource FlatButtonStyle}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

**Styles**

```
<!-- Style Collapsed-->
<Style x:Key="stackCollapsed" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=sentButton,Path=IsPressed}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Do you mean click once to show click second time to hide?

Comment: @dkozl yes :) exactly. Like a Javascript approach, but this is for desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Button` use `ToggleButton` and bind `StackPanel.Visibility` to `ToggleButton.IsChecked` property via `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` converter

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="sentButton" Content="Add Friend" Margin="493,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="106"/>
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding ElementName=sentButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <Label Content="Invite Friends" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,477,0" Height="32" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="26,0,0,0">
        <Label Content="Enter your friend's email" Width="222" Height="25" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  x:Name="textBoxEmail" Width="298"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Send" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Width="77" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

where converter is defined as below

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `Visibility` property in the `<StackPanel>` tab takes a higher precedence than anything set in a Style or Trigger, so the Trigger never gets applied. See the [Dependency Property Precedence List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx#listing) for more details.

To fix your current solution, move the Visibliity property out of the `<StackPanel>` tag and into your Style, like this :

```
<Style x:Key="stackCollapsed" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=sentButton,Path=IsPressed}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<StackPanel Style="{DynamicResource stackCollapsed}">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

That said, I would personally recommend something like a Toggle Button with the `StackPanel.Visibility` bound to the `ToggleButton.IsChecked`, like [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37398431/302677).

Comment: thanks for your answer, your method works but the stackpanel didn't fix, is like showing and hiding (only if I long press the button)

Comment: @Antoine Yep, that's because `Button.IsPressed` is only true while you hold the mouse down on it. That's why `ToggleButton` is a better choice.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple as Stackpanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved set the Children to null

```
stackPanel.Children.Clear();
```

this work if you need to show / hide the panel the first time, it doesn't work if you need to do runtime