# How can I hide and display a TextBlock by clicking ToggleButton using MVVM pattern C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to hide the TextBlock when I click the ToggleButton once and display it in other click using MVVM pattern in c# with animation and make it multiple using code to use it in multiple Windows

Comment: Please check the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778802/binding-commands-to-togglebutton-checked-and-unchecked-events

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackPanel Collapsed and Visible on Button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398233/stackpanel-collapsed-and-visible-on-button-click)

Comment: Please read our [ask] topics before asking a question.